# multiple clicks on custom tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom tableView cell, When I click on the cell the height of the cell increases (the cell expands):

```
 var selectedIndex:IndexPath?
    var isExpanded = false

    func didExpandCell(){

        self.isExpanded = !isExpanded
        self.TableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndex!], with: .automatic)
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        self.didExpandCell()
    }
```

I would like to click the cell a second time and segue to another view controller; is this possible?

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: tableView)
```

Comment: add relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` method you have to check whether the cell is expanded or not. If it is expanded try calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "details", sender: tableView)`. If it is not then implement the code to expand the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way other than checking for `isExpanded` state:
In `didSelectRowAt`, put a condition to check whether selected cell's height is equal to the expanded cell height (For ex., if the expanded cell height is set to 100 static). If `YES`, then call `performSegue`

**The following is just a pseudocode for the logic:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   let cell = getCellForIndexPath(indexPath)

   if cell.frame.size.height == 100 { // 100 is assumed to be static height for expanded cell. If it is dynamic, compare with normal cell height
      performSegue()
   } else {
      self.didExpandCell()
   }
}
```